# Hot Deployment in JBoss Application Server 4.2 for Javascript files

Tags: jboss

I have been using Apache and Weblogic, new to JBoss. Currently I have my local instance of the JBOSS Server and I need to restart the server every time i change a js file in the code in order to reflect that change, however small that change is.
I am using ExtJS in my application and the file which I am changing is located in:

C:\Sandbox\Jboss-4.2.0cp09\jboss-as\server\myserv\deploy\App.sar\App.ear\App.war\mymodule\sample.js

Is this how the AS is setup or can I modify any settings to make it reflect the changes on the fly by hitting the browser refresh button?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

what we do to improve performance of the application server is to deploy the static content like image / css / js ; in the apache document_root which will deliver the files from here and not from JBOSS with your EAR.

But you need to change the code of your application to manage this behavior, but the benefit is very surprising ;)
So once it's done you could then change any file outside of the EAR so on the file system of the apache server, like you want.

nota : we do this like that at my company because it's not the role of an application server to deal with js/css/images ; an app server is too heavy for this so little task.

Hope this could help.